# What is the alternative way of querying _all from elasticsearch 6.x onwards?

Tags: elasticsearch

As mentioned in the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/mapping-all-field.html), from elasticsearch 6.x `_all` has been deprecated. I have a `matchQuery` like below

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", typeAndName.name))
                        .should(buildMatchQuery(
                                SearchFields.kObjectNameKey,
                                dataModel.getLowerFieldName(PropertyType.STRING, SearchFields.kObjectNameKey),
                                typeAndName.name));
```

Can someone suggest someway what is the recommended way of doing the same now?

In my case, I don't know beforehand what all fields can be there in the index so I cannot use `copy_to` in index mapping to copy all fields data to some other field to simulate all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in [elasticsearch community](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-alternative-way-of-querying-all-from-elasticsearch-6-x-onwards/228749/4?u=deb)

> You should be able to specify it for dynamic mappings through an index
>   template.

Dynamic template approach is explained in more detail in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229131/785523).